# mysql master-slave. can i add slave when the master server already has a lot of data

Tags: mysql, database, master-slave

is there a way to replicate mysql while the master server already has a lot of data.I tried the normal way, but I had difficulty getting the `MASTER_LOG_POS` value. how can the slave server be able to replicate data that previously existed on the master server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you start with an exact full copy of your existing database. This means creating a real copy of your MySQL data directory (while the server is *off*), go with a (consistent) snapshot, or use a tool like Percona XtraBackup.

Only after you have 2 identical MySQL servers, you can start replicating. Note that using a tool like `mysqldump` is not a good idea for consistent snapshots.

Comment: i found ways in this [website](https://www.schalley.eu/2017/01/16/setting-up-mysql-replication-with-existing-data-master-slave/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relatively small amount of data you could use mysqldump --master-data=1 --single-transaction. This will create a snapshot with the correct master-binlog and position required. This should not be used for production environments or large amounts of data.